# Spring Crontab pattern: every weekday at specific times

Tags: java, linux, spring, unix, cron

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html) is the documentation for the Spring Crontab syntax.

I want to run a task every weekday at 14:40, 14:45, 14:50, 14:55, and 15:00, but I can't figure out how to express this with a Crontab pattern. The closest I've come up with so far is:

```
0 40/5 14 * * MON-FRI
```

But this doesn't run at 15:00.

Is this possible to express with a Crontab pattern at all?

Answer (score 0):

You need to split it into two expressions :

```
0 40-55/5 14 * * MON-FRI
0 0 15 * * MON-FRI
```

If you only want to have one expression and you are okay with the last trigger time in a day run one minute before, you can use :

```
0 40-55/5,59 14 * * MON-FRI
```

Spring internally use `CronSequenceGenerator` to generate the next trigger time for a cron expression. You can use it to verify a cron expression.

For example , to verify the next several trigger times of `0 40-55/5,59 14 * * MON-FRI`:

```
CronSequenceGenerator generator = new CronSequenceGenerator("0 40-55/5,59 14 * * MON-FRI");

Date d = Date.from(LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    d = generator.next(d);
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

which will print out :

```
Tue Jun 02 14:40:00 HKT 2020
Tue Jun 02 14:45:00 HKT 2020
Tue Jun 02 14:50:00 HKT 2020
Tue Jun 02 14:55:00 HKT 2020
Tue Jun 02 14:59:00 HKT 2020
Wed Jun 03 14:40:00 HKT 2020
Wed Jun 03 14:45:00 HKT 2020
Wed Jun 03 14:50:00 HKT 2020
Wed Jun 03 14:55:00 HKT 2020
Wed Jun 03 14:59:00 HKT 2020
```